# Constraints for a function arguments in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, arguments, constraints

What is the best practice to make constraints for function arguments.
similar to one that checks that check negative numbers inside logarithm function:

```
SELECT log(-1, 1)
```

throws error:

```
[2201E] ERROR: cannot take logarithm of a negative number
```

So far I found a way to do it using PL/pgSQL inside a function body but it doesn't look like a good solution for me.
 Is there a way to make constraints in a function declaration?
I would like to see something like this: (this code does not work)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.logloss(y_true BOOL NOTNULL, y_pred FLOAT NOTNULL)
```

Or maybe (this does not work as well)

```
CASE WHEN __condition__ RAISE EXCEPTION 
  ELSE __function__body
END
```

Answer (score 3):

> So far I found a way to do it using PL/pgSQL inside a function body but it doesn't look like a good solution for me.

Personally I don't know what could be wrong with this approach. It's rather simple and clear, e.g.

```
create or replace function test_1(arg integer)
returns integer language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if arg < 0 then
        raise exception 'The argument cannot be negative.';
    end if;
    return arg;
end $$;

select test_1(-1);

ERROR:  The argument cannot be negative.
```

There is no built-in feature to automatically check arguments of a function. However, you have an alternative. You can define [domains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html) for arguments, example:

```
create domain non_negative_integer as integer
check (value >= 0);

create or replace function test_2(arg non_negative_integer)
returns integer language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return arg;
end $$;

select test_2(-1);

ERROR:  value for domain non_negative_integer violates check constraint "non_negative_integer_check"
```

Comment: Good use of Domains there @klin,  I would suggest using the name `uint` for the domain, as this keeps it consistent with other languages.   Would be nice if PostgreSQL added the ability to specify the error [code/message] on check failure.